# Sending email fails with mailbox unavailable

Tags: c#, windows, email, permissions, smtp

A console application was configured as a task and sending out emails on a regular basis on an application server(Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2)

We have had a patch on this system and now I see this Error message:
**Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender**

What setting or permissions have been affected? How do I go about solving this issue?

Code:

```
using (var mail = new MailMessage())
{
    mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = message;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    this.smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
```

Config:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp.domain.com" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>>
  </system.net>
```

StackTrace:

```
System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String serverResponse)
   at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.OnClose(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Net.ClosableStream.Close()
   at System.Net.Mail.MailWriter.Close()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Comment: where you define the `smtpClient` credentials?

Comment: are you supposed to be using your windows credentials to send the emails? are you using an exchange server or a 3rd party SMTP?

Comment: @un-lucky the SMTP credentials are defined in the config section the OP provided

Answer (score 3):

More than likely the problem is with this line of code

```
mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
```

and the fact that in your config you have set `defaultCredentials` to true.

your SMTP probably doesn't allow you to send emails anonymously as this user.

You have 2 options, set up your SMTP to allow anonymous sending of emails, or else explicitly provide the username and password for the user in question, setting `UseDefaultCredentials` to false.

Read this if you are using Exchange:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997170(EXCHG.140).aspx

Comment: I am in touch with the Email team. Thanks for the tip. I will confirm the answer once it is solved